# Rouché's theorem for $z^7-5z+1$ if $|z|>1$ and $|z|<3$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, rouches-theorem

I want to count number of zeros of  $z^7-5z+1$ for $\{z | 1 < |z| < 3 \}$. Using Rouché's theorem I found that the function has 1 zero ($0$) of multiplicity 1 in $\{z | 1 < |z|\}$ and 1 zero ($0$, the same!) of multiplicity 7 in $\{z ||z| < 3 \}$. And how many zeros do we finally have in  $\{z | 1 < |z| < 3 \}$?

The main problem is how one can count the difference? Why can we just writy that there are 6 zeros because $7-1=6$ and don't pay attention that $0$ is not in $\{z | 1 < |z| < 3 \}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first consider the disc $|z|<1+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ small positive quantity (thanks for @saulplatz's comment for this correction), and the 2 functions $g=z^7$ and $f=-5z+1$ since $|g|< 1+\epsilon<5(1-\epsilon) -1)<|f| $ on $|z|=1+\epsilon$ we have by Rouche's Theorem that $|f|$ and $|f+g|$ have the same number of zeros on the disc $|z|=1+\epsilon$- that is 1.
For $|z|<3$ we take $f=z^7$ and $g=-5z+1$. Obviously we have $|g|<|f|=3^7$ on $|z|=3$ so $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros inside $|z|<3$ which is 7. We thus conclude that in the annulus $1<|z|<3$ the function $z^7-5z+1$ has 6 zeros.

Comment: Why can we just writy that there are 6 zeros because $7-1=6$ and don't pay attention that $0$ is not in $\{z | 1 < |z| < 3 \}$?

Comment: It seems to me that you have proved that the function has $6$ zeros in $1\leq |z| <3$. Don't we need to consider $|z|<1+\varepsilon$ in the first case?

Comment: @Kelly I don't understand your comment.  If there are $7$ zeros in one set $S$, and $1$ in a subset $T\subset S$, there must must be $6$ zeros in $T\setminus S$

Comment: @Kelly. I think we need to exclude the zero of $z^7-5z+1$ in $|z|<1$

Comment: @saulspatz - I am not sure I understood your comment.

Comment: You've shown there is one zero in $S=\{z\mid |z|<1\}$ and seven zeros in $T=\{z\mid |z|<3\}$  That means there are six zeros in $T\setminus S=\{z\mid 1\leq |z|<3\}$  There might be a zero on $|z|=1$.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes - I got it , thank you. We need to exclude zeros on $|z|=1$. Let me add ot to the proof (I already know there are none).